# how to add constraint on a boolean data type in myql

Tags: mysql

so i make a database with mysql, with my database design i design 3 table (customer, product, order) and I need one of the table to have a boolean variable column. in that column I need to use constraint when the value is 0 so u cant add the product to the order table.

```
drop database trial;

create database trial;

use trial;

create table customer_details(
customer_id int not null,
customer_name varchar(100) not null,
customer_contact varchar(100) not null,
customer_address varchar(100) not null,
primary key(customer_id)
);

create table product_details(
product_id int not null,
product_name varchar(100) not null,
product_finishing varchar(100) not null,
product_price varchar(100) not null,
product_stock int check(product_stock >=0) not null,
product_condition_1ready_0mentah boolean not null check(1 >= product_condition_1ready_0mentah AND product_condition_1ready_0mentah >=0),
primary key(product_id,product_stock)
);


create table order_details(
order_id varchar(50) not null,
order_quantity int not null check(order_quantity > 0),
customer_id int not null,
product_id int not null,
order_date date not null,
order_desc varchar(255),
primary key(order_id),
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer_details(customer_id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product_details(product_id)
);

insert into product_details(product_id, product_name, product_finishing, product_price, product_stock, product_condition_1ready_0mentah)
values
    (1, "meja", "ash", "Rp 10000", 10, true),
    (2, "kursi", "redwood", "Rp 20000", 20, true),
    (3, "panel", "maple", "Rp 300000", 20, false);

insert into customer_details(customer_id, customer_name, customer_contact, customer_address)
values
    (1, "Test Meubel", "08987654321", "Solo");

insert into order_details(order_id, order_quantity, customer_id, product_id, order_date, order_desc)
values
    ("12345", 10, 1, 1, "2020-12-20", "Bla Bla Bla"),
    ("54321", 5, 1, 2, curdate(), "Notes bisa dimasukin sini");
```

so for the product_condition I need to have constraint if its false I cant add order for that specific product
what I need to do

Comment: Note that 5.7 fails and version 8 silently converts to tinyint https://dbfiddle.uk/vFFLksqu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to mysql and sorry if any of my opinion is wrong.

So what you want to do is to control whether the product is avaliable for INSERT on order_details by setting the product_condition_1ready_0mentah to 0\1.And I've come up with an idea to create a stored procedure to achive that.

Code below is the SP:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_order_details`(p_order_id varchar(50), 
                                                                    p_order_quantity int,
                                                                    p_customer_id int,
                                                                    p_product_id int,
                                                                    p_order_date date,
                                                                    p_order_desc varchar(255))
BEGIN
    if (select product_condition_1ready_0mentah from product_details where product_id=p_product_id) = 0 then
        select 'Not inserted, the product you choose is not avaliable!';
    else 
        insert into order_details(order_id, order_quantity, customer_id, product_id, order_date, order_desc) values
        (p_order_id, p_order_quantity, p_customer_id, p_product_id, p_order_date, p_order_desc);
    end if;
END
```

And I've tested if it works,here's the result:

[If you set it to 0, it wont insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCUV0.png)

[If you set it to 1, it will insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ACuH.png)

Hope this will help,and any correction will be appreciated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).